# Poner color a una celda de acuerdo a su contenido de una tabla extraída de Hojas de cálculos google mediante Query

Tags: javascript, java, html

Soy nuevo en esta comunidad y me urge tener orientaciones sobre lo comentado en el título lo cual explica mejor:

Estoy trabajando con Hojas de cálculo de Google. Estoy construyendo un sitio donde debo mostrar dichas hojas (ya sea completamente o realizando consultas query).

Logro visualizar dicha tabla en mi página pero me urge lo siguiente:
colocarle un color a la celda donde dice "Desertó".

Comparto enlace para descargar los archivos donde están los códigos. Gracias!
[Archivosaqui](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17-KngVHZHdX-W9dv1LdujlUx986Y565J?usp=sharing)

Answer (score -1):

Hola puedes hacer esa condicional directamente en tu hoja de calculo de google, selecciona la columna que necesitas realizar la condicional y da click derecho y luego en la opción "Formato condicional" y das click en "+ Agregar otra norma" ahí das la condicional de cambio de color"

Comment: Hola Javier.
Ya lo he pensado e intentado pero no resulta. Fíjate que ya cambie la hoja de cálculo como me indicas pero en mi página html no se refleja.